# SIGABRT in [RCTContextExecutor dealloc] every reload

Tags: ios, react-native, sigabrt

I'm new to `React Native`.
I follow [this official facebook tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html), and every time I change the code in the `index.ios.js` a `SIGABRT` exception araise in `RCTContextExecutor.m` at the `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
  [self invalidate];
}
```

And the update can perform. Can anyone help how to handle this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found how to solve the stopping on `XCODE` issue (but not the reason which is good enough):

1. Run the `react-native`
2. If run on simulator press `cmd+D`
3. If run on real device, shake the device
4. Press `Stop Profiling`